# Excel: aggregate data from two row argumant cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am aggregating an output of an SQL database and I can't think of the formula to extract the data I want from an unstructured sheet.

Format data is in:
[image]

What I would like the output to be:
[image]

Thank you in advance,

Tikhon

PS: I know I can concatenate the date and code string, and use that in an index/match formula but I don't want to mess with the SQL request sheet in any way. I was hoping for something cleaner.

Comment: A PivotTable will do the job

Comment: Don't think so - as it has to be dynamic. I actually found the answer on excel jet

Answer (score 0):

```
=INDEX(data, MATCH(1, ($A175 = date)*(C$9 = asset_class),0), MATCH($B$8,data_type,0))
```

The above works.

Got it from an external source - not sure what the rules are for linking here, credit goes to a Dave Bruns.